# question about postgresql bind variables

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I was looking at the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136789/how-do-you-make-python-postgresql-faster) and decided to try using the bind variables. I use

```
sql = 'insert into abc2 (interfield,textfield) values (%s,%s)'
a = time.time()
for i in range(10000):
    #just a wrapper around cursor.execute
    db.executeUpdateCommand(sql,(i,'test'))

db.commit()
```

and

```
sql = 'insert into abc2 (intfield,textfield) values (%(x)s,%(y)s)'
for i in range(10000):
    db.executeUpdateCommand(sql,{'x':i,'y':'test'})

db.commit()
```

Looking at the time taken for the two sets, above it seems like there isn't much time difference. In fact, the second one takes longer. Can someone correct me if I've made a mistake somewhere? using psycopg2 here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The queries are equivalent in Postgresql.

Bind is oracle lingo. When you use it will save the query plan so the next execution will be a little faster. `prepare` does the same thing in Postgres.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-prepare.html

psycopg2 supports an internal 'bind', not `prepare` with `cursor.executemany()` and `cursor.execute()`

(But don't call it bind to pg people. Call it prepare or they may not know what you mean:)

Answer (score 7):

---

**IMPORTANT UPDATE** :
I've seen into source of all python libraries to connect to PostgreSQL in FreeBSD ports and can say, that only **py-postgresql** does real prepared statements! But it is Python 3+ only.

also py-pg_queue is funny lib implementing official DB protocol (python 2.4+)

---

You've missed answer for that question about prepared statements to use as many as possible. "Binded variables" are better form of this, let's see:

```
sql_q = 'insert into abc (intfield, textfield) values (?, ?)'  # common form 
sql_b = 'insert into abc2 (intfield, textfield) values (:x , :y)' # should have driver and db support
```

so your test should be this:

```
sql = 'insert into abc2 (intfield, textfield) values (:x , :y)'
for i in range (10000):
    cur.execute(sql, x=i, y='test')
```

or this:

```
def _data(n):
    for i in range (n):
         yield (i, 'test')
sql = 'insert into abc2 (intfield, textfield) values (? , ?)'    
cur.executemany(sql, _data(10000))
```

and so on.

**UPDATE:**
I've just found [interest reciple](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576698-transparently-execute-sql-queries-as-prepared-stat/) how to transparently replace SQL queries with prepared and with usage of %(name)s

Comment: @Eir, i think in psycopg2 bind variables are specified like %(name)s, no?

Comment: I will be very carefil with this form of SQL and possibly will not use it in production.

Comment: @eir, think I was wrong with the my question. They both does the same stuff, but like what @nate and @forest has said, its specific to oracle.

Comment: All of the examples here do essentially the same thing in psycopg2: They pass a query and its parameters to the connector, which combines them and sends the resulting strings to the server.  (To be fair, it's hard to tell this is happening unless you examine psycopg2's source code.)  This is *not* what happens when you use "bind variables" (an Oracle phrase).  For "bind variable" behavior, you need to send the query and parameters to the server separately so the server's query planner has the opportunity to optimize with or without specific parameter values.

Comment: 'bind variables' and 'prepared statements' are **same**

Comment: I've checks code of psycopg2 and you're right for this library, But I don't specify which library to use in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, psycopg2 has never supported server-side parameter binding ("bind variables" in Oracle parlance).  Current versions of PostgreSQL do support it at the protocol level using prepared statements, but only a few connector libraries make use of it.  The Postgres wiki [notes this here](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Python_PostgreSQL_Driver_TODO).  Here are some connectors that you might want to try:  (I haven't used these myself.)

- [pg8000](http://pybrary.net/pg8000/)
- [python-pgsql](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-pgsql/)
- [py-postgresql](http://python.projects.postgresql.org/)

As long as you're using DB-API calls, you probably ought to consider cursor.executemany() instead of repeatedly calling cursor.execute().

Also, binding parameters to their query in the server (instead of in the connector) is not always going to be faster in PostgreSQL.  Note [this FAQ entry](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/FAQ#Why_is_my_query_much_slower_when_run_as_a_prepared_query.3F).

Comment: cursor.executemany() is 'bind' for pyscopg2 http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.executemany

Comment: You would think so, but if you look at the source code you'll see that psycopg2 uses the same code for execute() and executemany().  It does its own parameter binding within the library, rather than preparing a statement and sending it to the server for binding.

Comment: Therefore, psycopg2's executemany() might be marginally faster than execute() by remaining in compiled code instead of switching back to the python interpreter many times, but it's still not doing what is implied when you use the Oracle term "bind variables."

Comment: Unfortunately, the psycopg2 docs and the PostgreSQL docs use the word "prepare" to mean different things, which is confusing.  http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/interactive/libpq-exec.html

Comment: This http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_bind_variables.htm says that oracle is preparing each statement and keeping track of it by a hash index of the string. So then you would have to call prepare manually in pg for equivalency, right?

Comment: To give a Postgres server the opportunity to do what Oracle does with bind variables, you'll have to pass the query and its parameters to the server separately.  You can do this by using a connector that internally calls PQexecParams() / PQprepare() / PQexecPrepared(), using a connector that does the equivalent operation using the postgres wire protocol, or by using a PREPARE statement.  I would prefer one of the first two approaches because they would keep my application code cleaner and my queries more portable by avoiding explicit PREPARE statements.

Comment: Keep in mind that the Postgres server is in some ways less stupid than Oracle, and might perform just fine without the extra client-side work.  I advise the reader to measure real-world performance before complicating his life with premature optimization.