# SQL string substitution error not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to return a query to get all records that begin with string like a varibale i have
so i do so :

```
"""select name from pos_order where name like '%s'||'%' order by id DESC limit 1"""%(darsh[0])
```

where `darsh` is something like that `'mostafa/'`

but it keep telling me `not enough arguments for format string`

I don't know why.

Comment: Don't use string manipulation to add data to queries. Use query parameters instead.

Comment: didn't get it ?  what do you mean ?

Comment: If you're using psycopg2: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries Especially the red box a few screens down.

Comment: @Colonel Although the driver parameter passing mechanism should be used in instead of his own, that is not reason for a downvote. This comment is for anyone who downvoted not necessarily you.

Comment: Are you using psycopg2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python tries to substitute both '%' characters in your sql. But it only has one value - darsh[0] - to use. Hence the error message, it is trying to fill in two values, but you've only given it one.

To prove this, escape the second %%, making your statement

"""select name from pos_order where name like '%s'||'%%' order by id DESC limit 1"""%(darsh[0])

***but*** Don't do this - it makes you vulnerable to SQL Injection. For example, if you had a function in your database called DO_BAD_THING a malicious user could make that function execute using a carefully crafted input string.

The correct answer is to use a bind variable, see this question :

[question about postgresql bind variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4263508/question-about-postgresql-bind-variables)

For an example of how to do this.

For emphasis - don't use string concatenation for SQL for *anything* where an end user can ever manipulate the string.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

It would be necessary to escape the `%` with another `%` like in `%%`

```
"""select name from pos_order where name like '%s'||'%%' order by id DESC limit 1"""%(darsh[0])
```

But that is bad practice as it opens the door to SQL injection. As you are using Psycopg use the `cursor.method` parameter passing:

```
cursor.execute("""
    select name 
    from pos_order 
    where name like %s||'%%' 
    order by id DESC 
    limit 1
    """, (darsh[0],)
)
```

The binding cited in the accepted answer is used for prepared statements which is not your case.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful :)