# Python List to PostgreSQL Array

Tags: python, postgresql

I have a list:

```
[u'ABC', u'DEF', u'GHI']
```

I have to insert it into a postgresql array:
(`ALTER TABLE "aTable" ADD COLUMN "Test" text[];`)

The syntax for adding data to the postgresql is:

```
update "aTable" SET "Test" = '{"ABC", "DEF", "GHI"}'
```

How can I convert the list to the correct format?

Comment: it's a pretty straightforward task, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list = [u'ABC', u'DEF', u'GHI']
list = str(map(str, list))

list = list.replace('[', '{').replace(']', '}').replace('\'', '\"')

query = '''update "aTable" SET "Test" = '%s\'''' %(list)
print query
```

Will result in to,

```
update "aTable" SET "Test" = '{"ABC", "DEF", "GHI"}'
```

Comment: Ending part is not correct in terms of sql best practices. It is rarerly recommended to enclude values in executed sql, rather it is recommended to use bind variables.

Comment: @alko could you post how to do this in sql best practice, instead of just saying it's "pretty straightforward" and telling how NOT to do it? Because I used to do something like Atul Arvind's answer myself once or twice..

Comment: @Patrick added an anwer, please check it for PostgreSQL (I can't test it atm)

Comment: your solution allows SQL injection.

Comment: This is a horrible answer. All other answers are better than this one. It is absolutely incomprehensible to me how this can be the accepted answer. It allows for SQL injection and does not properly replace characters in general (what if your values actually do contain square brackets or quotation marks?)

Comment: @scravy, I agree with your point today, It is my childhood mistake. today I can say there are better ways to do this. I am not sure why the questioner had accepted my answer, I think exhuma's answer is providing more helpful insight. nevertheless, once I will get the time will update with a better approach.

Answer (score 22):

Note that with `psycopg2` you don't need to do any string processing for arrays. This is considered as bad practice as it is error-prone and can - in the worst case - lead to opening up injection attacks! You should always use bound parameters. In the code below, I will create a new table with only one column with the type `TEXT[]` (as in your original question). Then I will add a new row, and update all of them. So you will see both an `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operation (although both are pretty much identical).

There is one Python gotcha though if you update with only one value: `cur.execute` expects the SQL statement as first argument and an *iterable* containing the parameters to be bound as second argument. The following will *not* work:

```
from psycopg2 import connect

conn = connect('dbname=exhuma')
cur = conn.cursor()
stmt = 'UPDATE foo SET example_value=%s'
new_values = ['a', 'b', 'c']
cur.execute(stmt, (new_values))
conn.commit()
```

The reason is that `(new_values)` is seen by python as `new_values` (the parens are dropped in this case, they are not seen as tuple). This will result in the error that you supply 3 values (`'a'`, `'b'` and `'c'`) as values to be bound, but there's only one placeholder (`%s`) in the query. Instead you must specify it as follows (notice the added comma at the end):

```
from psycopg2 import connect

conn = connect('dbname=exhuma')
cur = conn.cursor()
stmt = 'UPDATE foo SET example_value=%s'
new_values = ['a', 'b', 'c']
cur.execute(stmt, (new_values,))
conn.commit()
```

This will make Python see `(new_values,)` as a tuple (which is an iterable) with one element, which matches the query place-holders. For a more detailed explanation of the trailing comma, see [the official docs on tuples](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

Alternatively, you could also write `[new_values]` instead of `(new_values,)`, but - in my opinion - `(new_values,)` is cleaner as tuples are immutable, whereas lists are mutable.

---

Here's the table with which I tested:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    values TEXT[]
);
```

And here's Python code both inserting and updating values:

```
from psycopg2 import connect


conn = connect('dbname=exhuma')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('INSERT INTO foo VALUES (%s)', (['a', 'b'], ))

print('>>> Before update')
cur.execute('SELECT * FROM foo')
for row in cur:
    print(type(row[0]), repr(row[0]))

print('>>> After update')

cur.execute('UPDATE foo SET example_values = %s',
            (['new', 'updated', 'values'],))

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM foo')
for row in cur:
    print(type(row[0]), repr(row[0]))

cur.close()
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

On each execution, the code will insert a new row with the same array values, then execute an update without `WHERE` clause, so all values are updated. After a couple of executions, I this gives the following output:

```
>>> Before update
(<type 'list'>, "['new', 'updated', 'values']")
(<type 'list'>, "['new', 'updated', 'values']")
(<type 'list'>, "['new', 'updated', 'values']")
(<type 'list'>, "['new', 'updated', 'values']")
(<type 'list'>, "['new', 'updated', 'values']")
(<type 'list'>, "['a', 'b']")
>>> After update
(<type 'list'>, "['new', 'updated', 'values']")
(<type 'list'>, "['new', 'updated', 'values']")
(<type 'list'>, "['new', 'updated', 'values']")
(<type 'list'>, "['new', 'updated', 'values']")
(<type 'list'>, "['new', 'updated', 'values']")
(<type 'list'>, "['new', 'updated', 'values']")
```

Comment: Thanks, this doesn't require any data-type manipulation and hence should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Great answer. But maybe add the "commit" part to the first two examples. Haven' used psycopg2 in a while and thought your example had some mistake, but it was just me forgetting to commit until I read the remainder of your answer :-)

Comment: Thanks @BritishSteel. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

You just pass that list as a parameter to `execute`.  You don't need to do anything special.  Psycopg converts Python lists into a suitable PostgreSQL array literal.

```
import psycopg2 as dbapi

conn = dbapi.connect(dsn='')
c = conn.cursor()
x = [u'ABC', u'DEF', u'GHI']
c.execute('update "aTable" SET "Test" = %s', [x])
```

Comment: are those enclosing square brackets needed for `[x]` in execute? and you have wrong number of `)` brackets.

Comment: And downvoting all other answers without any comments do not seem me reasonable. You could have modified that cw post instead.

Comment: The square brackets are needed because the second argument of `execute` is a list (sequence) of parameters.  In this case, the first parameter happens to be a another list.

Answer (score -1):

Proper way of handling variables in SQL is usage of bind variables. To my knowledge, this is crucial for MySQL and Oracle DB, and I believe for [PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/137320/1265154) as well.

So better code would be along the lines

```
def as_array(l):
    l2str = ','.join('"{}"'.format(x) for x in l)
    return '{{{}}}'.format(l2str)

query = '''update "aTable" SET "Test" = %s'''
lst = [u'ABC', u'DEF', u'GHI']

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(query, as_array(lst))
```

where conn is a connection to PostgreSQL db.

Comment: thx for this answer, i can't test it right now either, but i'll try to remember this for the next time i'll need that ;-)

Comment: This is not needed. The bound value will automatically be bound properly. There's no need to call `as_array`. I will add an example in a second.