# Convert Postgres JSONB array into Javascript array of JSON elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, postgresql

I'm having some issues with postgresql(9.4) and javascript. I'm trying to convert a jsonb[] datatype into an array/list of json values in javascript. For simplicity, my example contains only one element(json) in the array.

```
var s = { "player": "{\"{\\\\\"username\\\\\": \\\\\"JetJet13\\\\\", \\\\\"points\\\\\": 525, \\\\\"level\\\\\": 3"}\"}" };
```

Here's what I have tried so far.

```
JSON.parse(s.player); //this gives an error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

Here's what I'm looking for.

```
var s = { "player": [ {"username": "JetJet13", "points": 525, "level": 3} ] };
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The string you have provided as output from Postgres doesn't match your desired parsed result - the JSON produced by Postgres doesn't declare an array as the value of `player`, rather an object within an object (which is illegal, as is evident by the error produced on parsing). How are you generating the JSON from Postgres?

Comment: `'{1, 2, 3, 4}'` is what an array looks like in postgres. Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699196/python-list-to-postgresql-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I managed to figure out how to get my desired result.

I've created a function to make things easier. Notice that the syntax highlighter gets confused with my regex expressions. A correction/alternative regex expression would be appreciated. I use Sublime Text 3 and it too is not interpreting the regex properly.

```
var convertJSONarray = function(s){

  var step1 = s.replace(/"{/g,'{').replace(/}"/g,'}').replace(/\\/g,"");
  //step1 = "{ {}, {}, {},...}"
  var step2 = "[" + step1.slice(1,-1) + "]";
  // step2 = "[ {}, {}, {}, ...]"
  var step3 = JSON.parse(step2);
  // step3 = [ {}, {}, {}, ...] the desired result :)
  return step3;
 };
```

Cheers.