# Inserting Python arrays into Postgres queries with psycopg2 leads to Type Error

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a list called `people2` like so:

```
['xloS4ooQOT',
 '3s4LyNyHs3',
 'NRL6zNePCT',
 '7hkLogfk8T',
 '5JcUkJ8FLO',
 'LZ6DMUfnEA',
 'CmBaomzMXC',
 'M5OPb0yf09',
 'CqG2XYGPxk']
```

I am trying to use it as the basis for a postgres query via the `psycopg2` module:

```
query = "SELECT userid, measurementvalue FROM db WHERE userid IN (%s)"
cur.execute(query, people2[1:5])
```

That produces the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-5825c6e2c3fa> in <module>()
      1 query = "SELECT userid, measurementvalue, displaydate, datatype FROM parse_dataobject WHERE userid IN (%s)"
----> 2 cur.execute(query, people2[1:5])
      3 for r in rows[:5]:
      4     print(r)

TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

I also tried removing the parentheses, but this leads to the same result:

```
query = "SELECT userid, measurementvalue, displaydate, datatype FROM parse_dataobject WHERE userid IN %s"
```

I am simply trying to follow the docs + previous posts ([Python List to PostgreSQL Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699196/python-list-to-postgresql-array)), but I seem to be missing something. What is wrong with what I'm doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From psycopg2 doc on [Lists adaptation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#lists-adaptation), your code should look like this:

```
query = "SELECT userid, measurementvalue FROM db WHERE userid = any(%s)"
cur.execute(query, (people2[1:5],))
```

Answer (score 0):

Python tuples are converted to sql lists in psycopg2:

`cur.mogrify("SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN %s;", ((1,2,3),))`

would output

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN (1,2,3);`

you need convert the list in tuple and after use this tuple, for example:

`people2 = ['xloS4ooQOT', '3s4LyNyHs3', 'NRL6zNePCT', '7hkLogfk8T', '5JcUkJ8FLO', 'LZ6DMUfnEA', 'CmBaomzMXC', 'M5OPb0yf09', 'CqG2XYGPxk']`

`query = "SELECT userid, measurementvalue FROM db WHERE userid IN %s"
 cur.execute(query, tuple(people2[1:5]))`