# PostgreSQL: PL/Python function not taking ARRAY input parameter

Tags: python, postgresql, plpython, postgres-plpython

## Objective:

- Creating a full text search engine using PostgreSQL FTS.

### Populating tsvector:

I have a tsvector column.
To populate tsvector column, I am executing a trigger which calls a procedure which executes a custom PL/Python function.

### Steps followed:

#### Trigger and Procedure function

Its something similar to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/textsearch-features.html#TEXTSEARCH-UPDATE-TRIGGERS trigger which calls **messages_trigger** procedure(written in plpgsql).

But instead of `coalesce(new.title,'')` and `coalesce(new.body,'')`, I am calling a [UDF](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/plpython-funcs.html) which has ARRAY of text as an input parameter.

```
custom_udf(p_arr ARRAY)
```

### Error:

During ingestion of data, it throws the error:

```
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedObject: type p_arr[] does not exist
```

### Question:

Is [ARRAY](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types) type parameter not allowed for Pl/Python function?

To by pass the issue, I am doing a comma separated join of list elements and passing that to the custom_udf. And inside custom_udf, I am using comma delimiter split to get back the list.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you used:

```
CREATE FUNCTION custom_udf(p_arr ARRAY) RETURNS ...;
```

means the same as

```
CREATE FUNCTION custom_udf(p_arr[]) RETURNS ...;
```

That is, a function with one unnamed parameter that has the data type “array of `p_arr`”. So PostgreSQL expects `p_arr` to be a data type, which explains the error message.

There is no “array” data type in PostgreSQL, you always have to name the element type, for example `integer ARRAY` or, equivalently, `integer[]`.

So, assuming that you want an array of strings, your definition should look like

```
CREATE FUNCTION custom_udf(p_arr text[]) RETURNS ...;
```

Comment: How do I pass the list from the calling procedure?
Inside the trigger procedure, if I am writing
`NEW.tsvector_report := to_tsvector('english', custom_udf(['elem1'])`
it throws error: `psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "["`

The syntax mentioned in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/arrays.html#ARRAYS-INPUT to pass array would mean manipulating **python list** into a **pgsql array** format.
Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Seems to me that my original idea of passing string into `custom_udf` and inside it split text into list is an easier way.

Otherwise, it would mean manipulation of string as done in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20699609/282155

Comment: You can pass a string array either as `'{string1,string2}'` or as `ARRAY['string 1', 'string 2']`.