# Updating PostgreSQL Table

Tags: python, postgresql, list, psycopg2

I have an Issue with updating SQL columns with lists in Python.

I have list `list_arrive` and I can't update my values in arrive column in PostgresSQL. Included list as an example

```py
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import numpy as np
# Getting values from Location.csv and converting it into DF Note:(I have Multiple Empty Rows and column arrive)
df = pd.read_csv("Locations.csv")
connection = psycopg2.connect(user="user",
                          password="password",
                          host="localhost",
                          port="5432",)
cursor = connection.cursor()
query = "SELECT * FROM location"
cursor.execute(query)

# I tried To Convert Df column type to str due to(TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting)Error
df['arrive'] = df['arrive'].astype(str)

# Replaced All Empty Rows With "NaN" Values
df['arrive'] = df['arrive'].replace(r'^\s*$', np.NaN, regex=True)

# Replaced "NaN" Values With None String
df['arrive'].fillna("None",inplace= True)   

# Created List 
list_arrive = list(df['arrive'])

sql_query = "UPDATE location SET arrive = %s"

# I tried:
cursor.execute(sql_update, (list_arrive,))
cursor.execute(sql_update, list_arrive)
# Tried with executemany
# Tried to Loop trough list_arrive
connection.commit()
list_arrive= ['Cranbury, NJ', 'None', 'New Orleans, LA', 'Ashland,VA', 'Lancaster, NY ', 'None', 'Hazelwood,MO', 'Aurora, CO', 'None']
```

Note that I'm updating only arrive column values in SQL database which has already other columns and values

I'm having three types of problem:

1. Getting "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"
2. When I tried to just `execute()` it pasted first value over and over with `{}` brackets
3. If I use `for` loop, it loops with just first values.

Comment: Your `UPDATE` has no `WHERE` clause so all the rows in the table will get the same value for `arrive`. Iterate over the list and pass value to `%s` as `(list_value,)`, again you need to specify which row to `UPDATE` with a `WHERE'.  Otherwise the `arrive` will be the last one passed and it will be the same for all rows. FYI, I'm pretty sure this; `import numoy as np` is supposed to be; `import numpy as np`

Comment: Please show your `executemany` call which should be work to pass multiple values to same parameter. Even show your `for` loop version. Don't just comment *you tried*.

Comment: `cursor.executemany(sql_update,list_arrive)` With Loop And execute many gives the same result @Parfait

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20699196/python-list-to-postgresql-array i even tried this one but not working somehow in my case @Parfait

Comment: I cannot see how `executemany` repeats only the first value! Anyway as commented above, without a `WHERE` clause you repeatedly update **all** rows, so the very last item in list is retained for field.

Comment: Please can u show example of this querry string, also i should specify WHERE as index?, and should i iterate index values through for loop too? @Parfait